# How to create a response related to the selection in previous page in web2py?

Tags: python, datatables, web2py

I have a csv table with field names-Fluid and Material. There are 2 kinds of fluid- Air and water and 2 materials corresponding to air (say M1 and M2) and 3 materials corresponding to water (say M2,M3 & M4). 
My first page of views displays the URL links to available Fluids i.e. Air and Water. I want to create a second page such that when the user clicks on Air, he gets URL links of M1 and M2 while if he clicks Water, he gets URL links of M2,M3 and M4.
How to do this? I am new to python and web2py.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary for fluid and material.

```
fluid_materials = {'Air':('M1','M2'), 'Water':('M2','M3','M4')}
```

Use the key to get the materials for the fluid.

```
f = 'Air'
fluid_materials[f]
```